# Regex that will only match in filenames

Tags: python, regex

I need a regex that will only match whatever is in the filename even when I give it the whole path, for example matching for `x64` and `nono`:

```
x64/x64/x64/lol/me.me <- will NOT match
nono.meme <- will match
god_knows/x64.something <- will match
lalala <- will NOT match
somewhere/subfolder/x64-headache/out/gg.exe <- will NOT match
nono/launcher.exe <- will NOT match
```

I've tried many variations, the most promising was `.*(x64|nono)(?!\/).*`, but it also matches 'somewhere/subfolder/x64-headache/out/gg.exe' which I don't want. I've also tried adding `[^\/\n]*` in front of it or adding another '.*?' in the middle but that had either no effect or completely broke it.

Of course, I've tried searching this on Google, but all the results I found were only for parsing filenames after a match or they recommended preparing the path so only the filename is being matched, but that is unfortunately not a possibility in my situation.

Comment: why not use `basename`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to *replace* the `.` that's after the matched text (which accepts any character, including a path separator) with `[^/]` (which does not). So, for example, `.*` becomes `[^/]*`.

You also need to anchor the regex to the end of the string using `$`, so that it will not accept stuff after the matched part and will ensure that the last `[^/]*` (i.e. excluding the `/`) is effective. (Not needed if you're using re.fullmatch() which implicitly anchors both start and end.)

If you're using re.match() which anchors to the start: `.*(x64|nono)[^/]*$`

If you're using re.search() which doesn't: `(x64|nono)[^/]*$`